# android - How to Intent RecyclerView in AdapterClass

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I need my `RecyclerView` Image can be pressed and go to next activity. I have the `Adapter` code.

```
public class MakananAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MakananAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<Makanan> makananList;

public MakananAdapter(ArrayList<Makanan> makananList)
{
    this.makananList = makananList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Makanan tanaman = makananList.get(position);
    holder.tvJudul.setText(tanaman.judul);
    /*holder.tvHarga.setText(tanaman.harga);*/
    holder.ivFoto.setImageDrawable(tanaman.foto);
    holder.tvJudul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(makananList!=null)
        return makananList.size();
    return 0;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView ivFoto;
    TextView tvJudul;
    TextView tvHarga;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivFoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        tvJudul = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewJudul);
        /*tvHarga = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHarga);*/
    }
}}
```

How to Intent RecyclerView in AdapterClass?

Comment: what is your problem tho?

Comment: Your onClick method is empty...

Comment: my problem is how can i intent the image from the adapter, because my imageview is from arraylist, and is not an activity

Answer (score 1):

Make your constructor like this

```
private Context context;
public MakananAdapter(ArrayList<Makanan> makananList, Context context) {
    this.makananList = makananList;
    this.context = context;
}
```

Pass the `context` when you initialize the adapter

```
MakananAdapter = new MakananAdapter(makananList, this);
```

And in adapter in your `onClickListner` do like this

```
holder.tvJudul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent openNextActivity = new Intent(context, yourActivityName.class);
        context.startActivity(openNextActivity)
     }
});
```

Comment: That's the correct answer of above question... need to pass Activity context on constructor to use Intents.